# How can I set Fedora 21 auto-login?

Tags: linux, users, automatic-logon, fedora-21

I would like to have my fedora installation boot up with 2/3 users automatically logged in. That is: non-root users logging in without password prompt.

Naturally they need not all have GUIs. I only need to be able to execute CLI programs and set processes to run at startup for each of these users.

Comment: After booting, do you mean that two users are logged in at the console, while the third (root) user is not?  In other words, a shell for each of those two users?

Comment: Yes that's correct. In fact, even if root gets a shell @ boot it wont make much of a difference (being that I can subsequently 'su' from anywhere, or just log in directly).

What I'm after essentially is that users (perhaps 2/3) auto-login  AND thereafter have commands /scripts that run automatically on each account.

Surely there is a way one can achieve this...right?

Answer (score 0):

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/137443/60622 works on Fedora 19, for one user.  For more users, try adding more `AutomaticLogin=` lines.  (I don't have a Fedora to try this on.  Years ago Slackware could autologin multiple text-mode consoles with `NO_PASSWORD_CONSOLE tty1:tty2:tty3:tty4:tty5:tty6`, so on *some* Linuxes it's possible.)

Comment: Ok. this looks promising. And I'm getting an idea of how I might do this already. Thing is I dont use GDM, I use LXDE.

Could you possibly specify a similar procedure for LXDE?
And am I right in suspecting this kind of automation is achieved via / after desktop initiation?

Comment: Ok. No such option exists under System >> Administration >> Users&Groups.

Also. I found autologin-user= (username) in the directly called lightdm. Setting those variables to the recommended values achieves nothing however.

Back to the drawing board.
Really - i want some apps to run on multiple user accounts, but I want them to log in automatically because to start them each manually would be a major Pain.

Currently looking into this:
http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/slackware-linux/169687-solved-how-autologin-console-13-1-a.html

Comment: (I'll let someone answer who can actually test on Fedora what they find online.)